# Multi Step Form - Only display active step

Tags: php, forms

So i am using the rhinoslider multi step form [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-multi-step-form-rhinoslider/)

HTML

```
<div id="page">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h3>Get a Phone Systems Quote Now </h3>
            <form action="http://www.adaptivecomms.co.uk/controllers/Contact.php" >

                <div id="slider">
                    <div class="form-step" >
                     <strong>Which brand of system are you looking for?</strong><br><br>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-left">Toshiba</div>
                            <div class="form-right"><input type="radio" id="brand" name="brand" class="form-input" /></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-left">NEC</div>
                            <div class="form-right"><input type="radio" id="brand" name="brand" class="form-input" /></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="form-left">Not Sure</div>
                            <div class="form-right"><input type="radio" id="brand" name="brand" class="form-input" /></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-step" >
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-left">Username *</div>
                            <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-input" /></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-left">Password *</div>
                            <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-input" /></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-left">Confirm Password *</div>
                            <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="cpass" name="cpass" class="form-input" /></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-step">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-left">Email *</div>
                            <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-input" /></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-left">Mobile No</div>
                            <div class="form-right"><input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" class="form-input" /></div>
                            <div class="form-error"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#slider').rhinoslider({
                controlsPlayPause: false,
                showControls: 'always',
                showBullets: 'always',
                controlsMousewheel: false,
                prevText: 'Back',
                nextText:'Proceed',
        slidePrevDirection: 'toRight',
    slideNextDirection: 'toLeft'
            });


            $(".rhino-prev").hide();
            $('.rhino-next').after('<a class="form-submit" href="javascript:void(0);"   >Next</a>');
            $(".rhino-next").hide();




            var info = ["","",""];
            var images = ["number1-icon.png","number2-icon.png","number3-icon.png"];
            $('.rhino-bullet').each(function(index){
                $(this).html('<p style="margin: 0pt; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;">    <img src="./img/'+
                    images[index]+'"></p><p class="bullet-desc">'+info[index]+'</p></a>');
            });





        });

        $('.form-submit').live("click",function(){

            $('.form-error').html("");

            var current_tab = $('#slider').find('.rhino-active').attr("id");

            switch(current_tab){
                case 'rhino-item0':
                    step1_validation();
                    break;
                case 'rhino-item1':
                    step2_validation();
                    break;
                case 'rhino-item2':
                    step3_validation();
                    break;
            }
        });

        var step1_validation = function(){

            var err = 0;

            if($('#brand').val() == ''){
                $('#brand').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Brand Name is   Required");
                err++;
            }
            if($('#lname').val() == ''){
                $('#lname').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Last Name is  Required");
                err++;
            }
            if($('#gender').val() == '0'){
                $('#gender').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Please Select   Gender");
                err++;
            }
            if(err == 0){
                $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-error").addClass("step-  success");
                $(".rhino-next").show();
                $('.form-submit').hide();
                $('.rhino-next').trigger('click');
            }else{
                $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-success").addClass("step-  error");
            }


        };

        var step2_validation = function(){
            var err = 0;

            if($('#username').val() == ''){
                $('#username').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Username is  Required");
                err++;
            }
            if($('#pass').val() == ''){
                $('#pass').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Password is  Required");
                err++;
            }
            if($('#cpass').val() == ''){
                $('#cpass').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("confirm Password  is Required");
                err++;
            }

            if(err == 0){
                $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-error").addClass("step- success");
                $(".rhino-next").show();
                $('.form-submit').hide();
                $('.rhino-next').trigger('click');
            }else{
                $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-success").addClass("step-error");
            }

        };

        var step3_validation = function(){
            var err = 0;

            if($('#email').val() == ''){
                $('#email').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("Email is Required");
                err++;
            }
            if(err == 0){
                $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-error").addClass("step-success");
                $(".rhino-next").show();
                $('.form-submit').hide();
                $('.rhino-next').trigger('click');
            }else{
                $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-success").addClass("step-error");
            }

        };
```

CSS

```
body { background-color:#fff; }
        #wrapper{
            border: 1px solid #DCDADA;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #E1E1E1;
            background: #fff;
            width:700px;
            height:480px;
            background:#f4f4f4;


        }
        #wrapper h3{
            font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            height:60px;
            background:url(img/title.png) no-repeat left top;
            margin:0;
            padding:16px 0 0 20px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
            filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=1, offy=1);
            color:#fff;
        }
        #slider {

            background: #fff;
            /*IE bugfix*/
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            width:700px;
            height:400px;   

        }

        #slider li { list-style:none; }

        #page {
            width:600px;
            margin:50px auto;
        }

        #slider{
            color: #000;
            background:#f4f4f4;
            font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            font-size:12px;
        }

        .form-step{
padding: 16% 3% !important;
        }

        .form-submit{
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6F95DC;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 20px 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 125px;
            z-index: 10;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#657dd1),  to(#334a99));
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#657dd1, #334a99);
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#657dd1, #334a99);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#657dd1, #334a99);
            filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#94b9e9,  endColorstr=#4870d2)";
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#94b9e9,  endColorstr=#4870d2)";
            font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

        }

        .errorDisplay{
            border:2px solid red;
        }

        .form-left{
            color: #717171;
            float: left;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .form-right{
            float: left;
            width: 214px;
        }
        .row{
float: left;
margin: 0px 0;
width: 100%;
        }
        .form-step input[type='text']{
            border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
            border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            height: 25px;
            padding: 3px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        select{
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            background: #FFF;
            padding: 2px;
            height: 30px;
            width:205px;
            font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            font-size:12px;
            background:#f4f4f4;
        }

        select option{
            font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            font-size:12px;
            background:#f4f4f4;
            color:#717171;
        }


        .form-error{
            color: red;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        .step-error{
            background:#f5715f !important;
            color:#FFF !important;
            -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 4px #C6C4C4
                -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 4px #C6C4C4
                box-shadow:1px 1px 4px #C6C4C4
        }
        .step-success{
            background:#72e487 !important;
            color:#FFF !important;
            -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 4px #C6C4C4
                -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 4px #C6C4C4
                box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 4px #C6C4C4
        }
        .bullet-desc{
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

This script initially showed all 3 steps and the current one was highlighted, as it is I replaced those 3 steps with my own images (the blue step 1, step 2 etc.) however what I want to achieve is for only the current step the user is on to be visible so when they complete info one step and click next they then only see 'step 2 of 3' for example. Also I am looking to move the active step to the right like this [image]

This is really part one of my issue. I won't mention the other bit yet as to avoid causing confusion. I am certainly not proficient with php so struggling with this one.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this? Here is a fiddle (but this isnt working so not sure if this is of any use http://jsfiddle.net/bz3yj/) and here is the form on the page http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/devform/index.html

Comment: Yes, I know. (Just to answer your question)

There are a few ways, you could make a PHP switch which is only outputing the active step. Depending on what you need maybe JavaScript would be easyer and faster to make a such a form.

Comment: Thanks wumm, I wouldn't have a clue how to do either. Have you got any pointers?